# Where should counter-reset be used when automatically numbering headings with CSS counters?

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I want to automatically number the headings with multiple levels of hierarchy in an HTML document using CSS. The examples I have found on the internet make extensive use of counter-reset, but I suspect this is often an incorrect use of counter-reset because it does not work for me under any configuration I have tested.

The h3 counter (subsection) should reset at each new h2.

Consider the following simple code example:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section subsection;
}

.countheads>h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section, upper-roman);
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

.countheads>h3::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section, upper-roman) "." counter(subsection);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="countheads">
    <h1>
      Main title
    </h1>

    <h2>
      Wuhhh
    </h2>

    <h3>
      First point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Second point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Third point
    </h3>

    <h2>
      Whoa
    </h2>

    <h3>
      First point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Second point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Third point
    </h3>


  </div>
</body>
```

The expected behavior is that subsections in section II start again at 1, as in II.1, II.2.

If I change the counter-reset statement to counter-set, I get the desired result:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section subsection;
}

.countheads > h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section, upper-roman);
  counter-set: subsection;
}

.countheads > h3::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section, upper-roman) "." counter(subsection);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="countheads">
    <h1>
      Main title
    </h1>

    <h2>
      Wuhhh
    </h2>

    <h3>
      First point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Second point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Third point
    </h3>

    <h2>
      Whoa
    </h2>

    <h3>
      First point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Second point
    </h3>

    <h3> 
      Third point
    </h3>


  </div>
</body>
```

With some syntax highlighters, the counter-set statement is marked red, implying an error, and yet it does what I want it to. But why doesn't counter-reset work in this case?

Comment: probably because it doesn't like counter to be reset on a pseudo (could be missing if added via a class/id missing), do it straight on H2

Comment: please keep your code unexpanded to make the reading easy. This will make the question more clear and we can notice that it's *focused* on one problem instead of having to scroll a lot to read it

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware that I had any control over whether the code was expanded or not.

Comment: @TemaniAfif apologies, thought those were image links

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset inside the `h2` and no the pseudo element:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section subsection;
}

.countheads > h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section, upper-roman);
}

/* .countheads > h2 + h3: use this selector in case you have an issue with Firefox */
.countheads > h2 {
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

.countheads > h3::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section, upper-roman) "." counter(subsection);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="countheads">
    <h1>
      Main title
    </h1>

    <h2>
      Wuhhh
    </h2>

    <h3>
      First point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Second point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Third point
    </h3>

    <h2>
      Whoa
    </h2>

    <h3>
      First point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Second point
    </h3>

    <h3>
      Third point
    </h3>


  </div>
</body>
```

`counter-set` will do the same because

> The value to set the counter to on each occurrence of the element. **Defaults to 0 if not specified.** If there isn't currently a counter of the given name on the element, the element will create a new counter of the given name with a starting value of 0 <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-set)</sup>

In your case, the counter already exist so it will not get created.

---

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#counter-reset):

> The `counter-reset` property **instantiates new counters on an element** and sets them to the specified integer values.

And

> The `counter-increment` and `counter-set` properties **manipulate the value of existing counters**. They only instantiate new counters if there is no counter of the given name on the element yet.

And more important

> The scope of a counter therefore starts at **the first element in the document that instantiates that counter** and includes the element’s descendants and its following siblings with their descendants.

So if you use `counter-reset` you wil create an instance with a scope limited to the pseudo element but using `counter-set` will simply modify the already instanciated counter on the upper level having a different scope.

To make a kind of analogy with programming language

```
int i = 0;
function a() {
   i = 0; /* this is counter-set */
}
function b() {
   int i = 0; /* this is counter-reset */
}
```

Comment: Adding counter-reset to h2 doesn't work. In the output, I see "II Whoa" then "II.4 First point".

Comment: @StephenBosch what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Firefox 83.

Comment: @StephenBosch it's probably a firefix bug then (will check) works fine on other browsers and it should be based on the described behavior in the specification

Comment: @StephenBosch for firefox do this `.countheads > h2 + h3 {
    counter-reset: subsection;
}` it should work fine

Comment: Why the difference?

Comment: @StephenBosch as I said, it's a bug in Firefox. Test my initial code using another browser and it will work fine. Another selector seems to work better for Firefox so you can use it but still remain a bug

Comment: So essentially, the correct way to do what I want is in fact to use counter-set. It puzzles me that there are so many examples out there that use counter-reset. I think people don't understand how counter-reset really works.

Comment: I expect Firefox to be fully standards compliant. If it is a bug, it needs to be reported. How do you know that this is a bug? Can you point me to documentation that establishes that this is faulty behaviour?

Comment: @StephenBosch it depends, it's all about scoping. Inside the pseudo element you are obliged to use counter-set but in an upper scope counter-reset will also work. In CSS there is a lot of ways to achieve the same output so many people are finding the counter-reset code and since it's working then let's use it.

Comment: @StephenBosch *Can you point me to documentation that establishes that this is faulty behaviour?* --> My answer above. I have explained the behavior of each property and I used the official Specifcation. I didn't even test in firefox initially since I woudln't expect it to not work there so It's clearly a bug for me.